# Database Design - Referencing a table multiple times from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, triggers, foreign-keys

Hi stackoverflow database design experts!

I'm facing a design problem in my database, and I've not found any similar issue in Stackoverflow, hence this question.

I have an image table, containing image data and it's primary key. In my design, each image can be referenced multiple time accross multiple tables.

Here is a representation of the database:

```
 --------------------    -------------------------------------------
| image              |  | table1                                    |
|--------------------|  |-------------------------------------------|
| id_image | data    |  | id_table1 | id_image | data               |
|----------|---------|  |-----------|----------|--------------------|
| 1        | Image 1 |  | 1         | 1        | References image 1 |
| 2        | Image 2 |  | 2         | 3        | References image 3 |
| 3        | Image 3 |   -------------------------------------------
 --------------------
 -------------------------------------------
| table2                                    |
|-------------------------------------------|
| id_table2 | id_image | data               |
|-----------|----------|--------------------|
| 1         | 2        | References image 2 |
| 2         | 2        | References image 2 |
| 3         | 3        | References image 3 |
 -------------------------------------------
```

Here are the tables detail:

- ***image table***

  - **id_image** auto-incremented primary key
  - **data** image data
- ***table1 table***

  - **id_table1** auto-incremented primary key
  - **id_image** foreign key referencing `image.id_image`
  - **data** table1 data
- ***table2 table***

  - **id_table2** auto-incremented primary key
  - **id_image** foreign key referencing `image.id_image`
  - **data** table2 data

I want my database to behave as follows:

- If I delete the `table1` row with `id_table1 = 1`, the image row with `id_image = 1` must be deleted (no other references to this image)
- If I then delete the `table2` row with `id_table2 = 1`, no image should be deleted (because the image with `id_image = 2` is still referenced by the `table2` row with `id_table2 = 2`)
- If I then delete the `table2` row with `id_table2 = 2`, the image row with `id_image = 2` must be deleted (no other references to this image)
- If I then delete the `table1` row with `id_table1 = 2`, no image should be deleted (because the image with `id_image = 3` is still referenced by the `table2` row with `id_table2 = 3`)
- If I then delete the `table2` row with `id_table2 = 3`, the image row with `id_image = 3` must be deleted (no other references to this image)

I've already tried some cascading delete, by inverting the foreign keys (i.e. `image` table containing `id_table1` and `id_table2` foreign keys), but if an image is referenced in 2 other tables, removing one referenced table entry also removes the image, which i do not want to happen.

I've also tried to define triggers, but this approach is more complex than I thought: each time I have to check among all foreign keys to `id_image` to see if there is another reference to the image to delete. This sample contains 2 foreign keys, but in the database I'm designing there will be more than 10...

I feel like there is a simple solution to this simple problem, anyone here to help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to delete (via trigger) from image when no id is left in either of the other 2 tables. Make a table with the union of their ids between them & image.

Comment: I just read your comment after writing my answer, and I feel that the solution I found is close to your suggestion!

Comment: There is no need for the proxy columns. (It is always the case that an id_tableN maps to a proxy that just maps back to it. Observe that not just proxys are FKs in tables 1 & 2, but (idN,proxy) is a FK. Don't need proxy.) (Why did you put them in? Do you think every table needs a surrogate?) Dropping them gives my suggestion. A FK says, subrow values must appear in another certain place as PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL. That's all that's going on. PS You have two *subtypes* of images, 1 & 2. Google re sql/database subtying/inheritance. That's faq, although you are asking about update algorithms.

Comment: This proxy table is here to simplify my triggers. Without it I'd have to check among all tables referencing an image to see if there is still a reference to the image impacted with the deletion. And if I add another table referencing an image, I'd have to update all existing triggers to also check this new table... Maybe I'm missing something here, feel free to detail your suggesion in an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a better design yesterday. It still uses triggers (as [Tab Alleman said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52206443/8295201)), but those are much simplier to define:

```
 --------------------    ---------------------------
| image              |  | image_proxy               |
|--------------------|  |---------------------------|
| id_image | data    |  | id_image_proxy | id_image |
|----------|---------|  |----------------|----------|
| 1        | Image 1 |  | 1              | 1        |
| 2        | Image 2 |  | 2              | 3        |
| 3        | Image 3 |  | 3              | 2        |
 --------------------   | 4              | 2        |
                        | 5              | 3        |
                         ---------------------------

 -------------------------------------------------
| table1                                          |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| id_table1 | id_image_proxy | data               |
|-----------|----------------|--------------------|
| 1         | 1              | References image 1 |
| 3         | 2              | References image 3 |
 -------------------------------------------------

 -------------------------------------------------
| table2                                          |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| id_table2 | id_image_proxy | data               |
|-----------|----------------|--------------------|
| 1         | 3              | References image 2 |
| 2         | 4              | References image 2 |
| 3         | 5              | References image 3 |
 -------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see in the schema above, I've introduced a new table: `image_proxy`:

- **id_image_proxy** auto-incremented primary key
- **id_image** foreign key referencing `image.id_image`

Also, `table1` and `table2` reference now an `image_proxy` entry instead of an `image` entry.

With this design, the triggers are now:

- After deleting entries in `table1`, delete corresponding entries in `image_proxy`.
- After deleting entries in `table2`, delete corresponding entries in `image_proxy`.
- After deleting entries in `image_proxy`, delete entries in `image` that are not referenced anymore in `image_proxy`.

I don't know if this design is the best for this issue, nor if triggers usage is safe, that's why I'll keep an eye on this post if there is any better answer or relevent comment!

Comment: Instead of triggers can you use a callback ? Something which is called on destroy of a record (after commit). It' easier to maintain such stuffs from code.

Answer (score 0):

Right away because of your first requirement:

> If I delete the table1 row with id_table1 = 1, the image row with
>   id_image = 1 must be deleted (no other references to this image)

I can tell you that you can only accomplish this with a TRIGGER.   The reason is because you want to automatically delete from the Parent table when a row is deleted from the Child table.

The reverse (Delete child when parent is deleted) can be done with Cascading Foreign Keys, but not this.

You will need to put Triggers on both child tables to enforce the logic you want.

Comment: Yes, but with this design the triggers will be very hard to define, as i said in my question. I'd rather use other designs, but I can't think of a better design yet...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not telling you Triggers are one option.  I'm telling you they are your only option.   They will require a little complex coding, sure, but that is the price of your requirements, sorry.